# Car Search With Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I made a program in Python to get onto Craigslist and search the area I want to find the car in the highest amount I would pay for the car and the lowest model year of any cars that I find. I wrote this to print the URL of the webpage with that car if the price was lower than $1800. But for some reason it prints things like "{PostingURL}" and "#" here is my code anyway to fix this would be a great help!

```
import time,httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import *
from splinter import *
browser = Browser()

browser.visit("http://fortcollins.craigslist.org/cta/")
browser.find_by_name("autoMinYear").fill("1990")
browser.find_by_name("maxAsk").fill("2000")
browser.find_by_id("query").fill("Longmont")
browser.find_by_id("searchbtn").first.click()
priceOfItem = browser.find_by_css("price")
if priceOfItem <= "1800":
    http = httplib2.Http()
    status, response = http.request('http://fortcollins.craigslist.org/search/cta?zoomToPosting=&catAbb=cta&query=Longmont&minAsk=&maxAsk=2000&autoMinYear=1990&autoMaxYear=&autoMakeModel=&excats=')
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_key('href'):
            print("\n")
            print("In Longmont")
            print link['href']
```

Comment: Why don't you build the URL instead? That would eliminate a lot of code that could cause your app to be unreliable. Like this: http://fortcollins.craigslist.org/search/cta?zoomToPosting=&catAbb=cta&query=&minAsk=1000&maxAsk=15000&autoMinYear=2005&autoMaxYear=2013&autoMakeModel=ford&excats=

Comment: A note unrelated to your larger issue: Using string comparisons on the prices the way you are won't work correctly. A price of `"900"` will not be reported (since `"1800" < "900"`) while a price of `"10000"` will be (since `"10000" < "1800"`). You probably want to convert the price to an `int`!

Comment: Thanks both of you guys! Very helpful! I'm gonna go add those changes real quick! Thank you very very much!

Comment: Why don't sort results by price? Also, why do you need a separate request and use `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Also, update to [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), the 3rd version is no longer being developed.

Comment: Will do! and thats brilliant! I actually didn't think of sorting by price!